# primary and foreign key relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to create two tables, one is having primary key and other for foreign key.

So my requirement is the values in users should be available which are present only in customers table other vice show error constraint violation.

Did something like this, but still am able to insert values in users which are not in customers.

```
create table if not exists customers
( 
    cust_user_id int, 
    primary key (cust_user_id)
);


create table if not exists users
(   prid INT,
    foreign key (prid) references customers(cust_user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Your table structure is correct, but you might be creating MyISAM engine tables instead of InnoDB - MyISAM is an older default and does not actually enforce foreign key constraints.  Try your two tables, but set the engine `create table...(....) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: ", but still am able to insert values in users which are not in customers" isn't that the way it's supposed to be?